# creating a data.frame from a larger data.frame based on index values

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops

I have two small data.frames (`d1`&`d2`) below. In `d1`, the column `post` varies across the rows (`length(unique(d1$post)) == 1L` gives `FALSE`).

From `d1`, I wonder how to form the following data.frame (ALWAYS, items with `1` suffix (ex. `mpre1`) are from `control==F` subset of the dataframe & items with `2` suffix (ex. `mpre2`) are from `control==T` subset):

```
# Desired output from `d1` (4 rows x 6 columns):
#  mpre1 sdpre1 n1 mpre2 sdpre2 n2
#1  0.31   0.39 20  0.23   0.39 18 ##group=1,control=F&T,outcome=1 
#2  3.54   1.21 20  3.08   1.57 18 ##group=1,control=F&T,outcome=2
#3  0.16   0.27 19  0.23   0.39 18 ##group=2,control=F&T,outcome=1
#4  2.85   1.99 19  3.08   1.57 18 ##group=2,control=F&T,outcome=2
```

In `d2`, the column `post` does NOT vary across the rows (`length(unique(d2$post)) == 1L` gives `TRUE`). From `d2`, I wonder how to form the following data.frame:

```
# Desired output from `d2`(4 rows x 6 columns):
#  mpre1 sdpre1 n1 mpre2 sdpre2 n2
#1  81.6   10.8 73 80.50 11.20  80 ##group=1,control=F&T,outcome=1
#2  85.7   13.7 66 90.30  6.60  74 ##group=1,control=F&T,outcome=2
#3  81.4   10.9 72 80.50 11.20  80 ##group=2,control=F&T,outcome=1
#4  90.4    8.2 61 90.30  6.60  74 ##group=2,control=F&T,outcome=2
```

The index values (for `group` & `outcome`) to extract the above vectors from either `d1` or `d2` are given by (I mean for `d1` put `d1` for `d2` put `d2`):

```
with(subset(d1,!control),rev(expand.grid(outcome=unique(outcome),group=unique(group))))
```

I have a list of these data.frames, thus a functional **BASE R** answer is highly appreciated (`d1`& `d2` are below).

```
(d1 = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/g.csv"))
#   study.name group  n mpre sdpre mpos sdpos post control outcome
#1      Diab_a     1 20 0.31  0.39 0.02  0.06    1   FALSE       1
#2      Diab_a     1 20 0.31  0.39 0.05  0.08    2   FALSE       1
#3      Diab_a     1 20 3.54  1.21 1.38  0.89    1   FALSE       2
#4      Diab_a     1 20 3.54  1.21 1.38  0.55    2   FALSE       2
#5      Diab_a     2 19 0.16  0.27 0.12  0.19    1   FALSE       1
#6      Diab_a     2 19 0.16  0.27 0.03  0.06    2   FALSE       1
#7      Diab_a     2 19 2.85  1.99 1.22  0.43    1   FALSE       2
#8      Diab_a     2 19 2.85  1.99 1.94  1.12    2   FALSE       2
#9      Diab_a     3 18 0.23  0.39 0.07  0.12    1    TRUE       1
#10     Diab_a     3 18 0.23  0.39 0.06  0.09    2    TRUE       1
#11     Diab_a     3 18 3.08  1.57 1.53  0.64    1    TRUE       2
#12     Diab_a     3 18 3.08  1.57 1.93  0.61    2    TRUE       2

(d2 = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/g2.csv"))
#  study.name group  n mpre sdpre mpos sdpos post control outcome
#1  Dlsk_Krlr     1 73 81.6  10.8 83.1  11.1    1   FALSE       1
#2  Dlsk_Krlr     1 66 85.7  13.7 88.8  10.5    1   FALSE       2
#3  Dlsk_Krlr     2 72 81.4  10.9 85.0   8.1    1   FALSE       1
#4  Dlsk_Krlr     2 61 90.4   8.2 91.2   7.6    1   FALSE       2
#5  Dlsk_Krlr     3 80 80.5  11.2 80.8  10.7    1    TRUE       1
#6  Dlsk_Krlr     3 74 90.3   6.6 89.6   6.3    1    TRUE       2
```

Comment: @anilGoyal, OP is using the 'group' for which 'control==T' as a reference. Thus, this reference group is what makes columns with suffix 2 like  'mpre2'.

Comment: Are you only looking for `base R` solutions?

Comment: Why is the group 2 not selected

Comment: it is from d1.  I was trying to understand your logic in that.  That logic of removing group2 is not clear because the `control` is `FALSE` for both groups and have the same 'outcome' values 1 and 2 along with post

Comment: I am working on it.  But, here is one issue.  Some rows are already duplicated in the input

Comment: Here is my code `d1new <- d1[!duplicated(d1[c('group', 'n', 'mpre', 'sdpre', 'control')]),];
 subd1 <- subset(d1new, select = c(group, n, mpre, sdpre, control));
 subd1$control <- subd1$control + 1;
 subd1$rn <- with(subd1, ave(seq_along(control), control, FUN = seq_along));
 out <- reshape(subd1[-1], idvar = "rn", direction = "wide", timevar = "control")[-1]`. There are some NA elements which should be filled with previous rows

Comment: There is still an issue in the NA elements which sshould be filled.  If it was tidyverse, it was easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
library(tidyverse)
d1 %>% select( n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
  unique %>%
  mutate(control = control + 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, names_glue = '{.value}{control}', 
              values_fn = list) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('1') | ends_with('2'), ~ifelse(post ==1, map_dbl(., first),
                                                         map_dbl(., last)))) %>%
  arrange(post) %>% 
  select(ends_with('1'), ends_with('2'))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  mpre1 sdpre1    n1 mpre2 sdpre2    n2
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.31   0.39    20  0.23   0.39    18
2  3.54   1.21    20  3.08   1.57    18
3  0.16   0.27    19  0.23   0.39    18
4  2.85   1.99    19  3.08   1.57    18
```

for `d2`?

```
d2 %>% select(n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
  mutate(control = control + 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, 
              names_glue = '{.value}{control}', values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(everything()) %>%
  select(ends_with('1'), ends_with('2'))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  mpre1 sdpre1    n1 mpre2 sdpre2    n2
  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1  81.6   10.8    73  80.5   11.2    80
2  81.4   10.9    72  80.5   11.2    80
3  85.7   13.7    66  90.3    6.6    74
4  90.4    8.2    61  90.3    6.6    74
```

If the strategy adopted in `d2` is near to your expectation, you can do similar for `d1 also

```
d1 %>% select(n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
  mutate(control = control + 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, 
              names_glue = '{.value}{control}', values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(everything()) %>%
  select(ends_with('1'), ends_with('2')) %>% unique

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  mpre1 sdpre1    n1 mpre2 sdpre2    n2
  <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1  0.31   0.39    20  0.23   0.39    18
2  0.16   0.27    19  0.23   0.39    18
3  3.54   1.21    20  3.08   1.57    18
4  2.85   1.99    19  3.08   1.57    18
```

Comment: The OP means that when column 'post' varies across the rows (ex. d1), then use only the first row of d1 for each unique 'group' value. But when column 'post' is constant across the rows (ex. d2), then use ALL the rows of d2 for each unique 'group' value. The OP wants these 2 logics for any other dataframes with any other values of 'group' and 'outcome'. Thus, OP has asked for a function that implements the above 2 logics to a list of data.frames that are similar to either d1 or d2.

Comment: Dear anil, if there are more than one group for which control==T, then everything is repeated. That is, mpre1 n1, sdpre1, remain the same and just repeat, but mpre2, sdpre2, n2, will be from the second group for which control==T.

Comment: Sir, Please see my code in last of my answer.  it works for both for `d1` and `d2`

Comment: Dear Anil, thank you. I get the following error: `Error in pivot_wider(., values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control,  : 
  unused argument (names_glue = "{.value}{control}")`

Comment: which version of `tidyverse` you are using?

Comment: `names_glue` was introduced in laterversion of `tidyr`

Comment: That is exactly why I kindly asked for a BASE R solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code in full **BASE R**. 
Then checked it on d1 and d2 dataframe. 
Then to checked it in an other dataframe, I created an imaginary dataset(d3) with 6 groups and 4 outomes 
I implemented them on tidyverse answer, The results are similar to my code. answer(albeit with different rows order, because I wanted to make it similar to the desired output order).
But the difference is that this code is written completely in BASE R as question required.

```
d1 <-  read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/g.csv")

d2 <-  read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/g2.csv")

d1_index <- rev(expand.grid(outcome = unique(d1$outcome), group =unique(d1$group)))

d2_index <- rev(expand.grid(outcome = unique(d2$outcome), group =unique(d2$group)))


df_fin <- function(index, data){
  group1 <- group2 <- data.frame()
  sd <- data.frame()
  group2_df <- group1_df <- final_df <- data.frame()
  Groups_list <- list()
  outcome_no <- range(data$outcome)
  
  for (i in unique(data$group)) {
    for (j in seq_len(range(outcome_no)[2])){
      couple <- subset(index, group == i & (outcome == j))
      
      subsetted_df <- subset(data, group == couple[1, 1] & (outcome == couple[1,2] | outcome == couple[2,2]) & post == 1)
      
      if (TRUE %in% subsetted_df$control){
        subsetted_df <- subset(data, group == couple[1, 1] & (outcome == couple[1,2] | outcome == couple[2,2]))
        subsetted_df <- subsetted_df[order(subsetted_df$post),]
        
      } else {
        
        subsetted_df <- subset(data, group == couple[1, 1] & (outcome == couple[1,2] | outcome == couple[2,2]) & post == 1)
      }
      
      sd <- rbind(sd, subsetted_df)
      
    }
    
  }
  
  G1 <- subset(sd, control == FALSE)
  G2 <- subset(sd, control == TRUE)
  G2 <- G2[order(G2$post),]
  
  G1_r <- G1[,c("mpre", "sdpre", "n")]
  G2_r <- G2[,c("mpre", "sdpre", "n")]
  
  colnames(G1_r) <- c("mpre1", "sdpre1", "n1")
  colnames(G2_r) <- c("mpre2", "sdpre2", "n2")
  
  final_df <- cbind(G1_r, G2_r)
  return(final_df)
  
}

#Check the function(Base R) on d1,d2
# d1
df_fin(d1_index, d1)
##   mpre1 sdpre1 n1 mpre2 sdpre2 n2
## 1  0.31   0.39 20  0.23   0.39 18
## 3  3.54   1.21 20  3.08   1.57 18
## 5  0.16   0.27 19  0.23   0.39 18
## 7  2.85   1.99 19  3.08   1.57 18
#d2
df_fin(d2_index, d2)
##   mpre1 sdpre1 n1 mpre2 sdpre2 n2
## 1  81.6   10.8 73  80.5   11.2 80
## 2  85.7   13.7 66  90.3    6.6 74
## 3  81.4   10.9 72  80.5   11.2 80
## 4  90.4    8.2 61  90.3    6.6 74
#Creating an example dataframe d3 to ckeck the code functionality for other dataset

d3 <- d1
d3 <- rbind(d3, d1)

d3[13:24, 'group'] <- rep(c(4,5,6), each = 4)
d3[13:24, 'outcome'] <- rep(c(3,4), each = 2)
d3[13:24, 'mpre'] <- rep(c(111,999), each = 2)

d3_index <- rev(expand.grid(outcome = unique(d3$outcome), group =unique(d3$group)))


#Check on d3
df_fin(d3_index, d3)
##     mpre1 sdpre1 n1  mpre2 sdpre2 n2
## 1    0.31   0.39 20   0.23   0.39 18
## 3    3.54   1.21 20   3.08   1.57 18
## 5    0.16   0.27 19 111.00   0.39 18
## 7    2.85   1.99 19 999.00   1.57 18
## 13 111.00   0.39 20   0.23   0.39 18
## 15 999.00   1.21 20   3.08   1.57 18
## 17 111.00   0.27 19 111.00   0.39 18
## 19 999.00   1.99 19 999.00   1.57 18
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think your solution is of limited use as it only works when `outcome` is `1` or `2` but as I mention in my original post, I need a functional answer that can accommodate any index values for `outcome` and `group` as given by `rev(expand.grid(outcome=unique(outcome),group=unique(group)))`.

Comment: @rnorouzian, I editted my answer, creating a function to work by any groups and outcomes combinations.

Comment: Dear Killbill, thank you so much for your time and expertise. At the end, [this tidyverse solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67454324/7223434) provided me with the output I was looking for but I still prefer a BASE R solution, if possible.

Comment: Dear @rnorouzian, it's my pleasure. I really enjoy this kind of challenges and learn a lot from them. Now, I want you to check my answer again on your datasets (it is the same function). I checked the results of my code on d1,d2, and on an imaginary dataset(d3). and compare them to  the results of  "tidyverse" answer. they were completely the same(although with different order of rows, because I tried to make them similar to your desired output). So, according to your rule of "BASE R", I wonder to know if my answer is also functional and in accordance with the question's requirement. thanks.

Comment: Dear Killbill, I think you didn't use `@rnorouzian` at the start of your comment and that's why I was not notified that you left me a message (sorry!). You can check your function using this data: `dat <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/f.csv")` and then: `lapply(split(dat, dat$study.name), df_fin)`, if everything worked fine, that means your function is suitable for my purposes. I also suggest that you first simply do: `split(dat, dat$study.name)` and look at individual data.frames to see how `group`, `outcome`, and `control` apear in the data.frames. --Thanks!

Comment: Also, in `dat` in my previous component, `group.name` is the same as `group`, so you can do: `names(dat)[3] = 'group'` before trying your function.