# Reducing overlapping code to improve speed

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

My function `foo()` works perfectly fine. But I think there is some redundant/overlapping code in it that makes it become a bit slow.

For example, the `pre` and `pos` objects share the same calls to `pivot_wider()`, `unnest()` etc.

**My question is:** Given the overlap between the calls in `pre` and `pos` objects, can my code become a bit shorter so it runs faster? OR is it possible to achieve the exact same output using BASE R?

```
library(tidyverse)

foo <- function(data){

pre <- data %>% dplyr::select(n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(everything()) %>%
  dplyr::select(mpre_FALSE,sdpre_FALSE,n_FALSE,mpre_TRUE,sdpre_TRUE,n_TRUE,outcome) %>% unique %>% 
  rlang::set_names("mT","sdT","nT","mC","sdC","nC","outcome") %>% mutate(time = rep(0,max(row_number())))

pos <- data %>% dplyr::select(n, mpos, sdpos, control, outcome, post) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpos, sdpos, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(everything()) %>% 
  dplyr::select(mpos_FALSE,sdpos_FALSE,n_FALSE,mpos_TRUE,sdpos_TRUE,n_TRUE,outcome,post) %>% unique %>% 
  rlang::set_names("mT","sdT","nT","mC","sdC","nC","outcome","time") %>% arrange(time)

bind_rows(pre,pos) 

}

## EXAMPLE OF USE:
dat <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/f.csv")

lapply(split(dat, dat$study.name), foo)
```

Comment: @Dave2e, I triple-checked it works fine on my machine. please make sure you have the latest version of tidyvesrse. This incompatibility between vesrions of tidyvese was why I also asked if the exact same output could be achieved via BASE R.

Comment: Try running the function inside `purrr::map_*` after using `group_split()`.  May be that's going to be of some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on further requirement as stated in comments to turn the solution into a function `foo`, this may meet the requirements

```r
foo <- function(data, cols){
  
  cols <- c('rev.sign', 'time_wk', 'time_cat')
  
  data %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
    map_dfr(~ .x %>%
              dplyr::select(all_of(cols), study.name, n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
              pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
              dplyr::select(all_of(cols), study.name, mT = mpre_FALSE, sdT = sdpre_FALSE,
                            nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpre_TRUE, sdC = sdpre_TRUE, nC = n_TRUE, outcome) %>% 
              mutate(time = 0)
    ) %>%
    bind_rows(
      data %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
        map_dfr(~ .x %>%
                  dplyr::select(all_of(cols), study.name, n, mpos, sdpos, control, outcome, post) %>% 
                  pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpos, sdpos, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
                  dplyr::select(all_of(cols), study.name, mT = mpos_FALSE,sdT = sdpos_FALSE,nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpos_TRUE,
                                sdC = sdpos_TRUE,nC = n_TRUE,outcome,time = post) %>% unique
        )
    ) %>% unnest(everything()) %>% unique %>% arrange(study.name)
  
}

library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/f.csv")
cols <- c('rev.sign', 'time_wk', 'time_cat')

foo(dat, cols)
#> # A tibble: 522 x 12
#>    rev.sign time_wk time_cat study.name    mT   sdT    nT    mC   sdC    nC
#>    <lgl>      <int>    <int> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 FALSE          0        1 A1          1.68  1.07    25  1.44  1.08    25
#>  2 FALSE          2        2 A1          1.68  1.07    25  1.44  1.08    25
#>  3 FALSE          0        1 A1          7.4   2.22    25  1.08  1.12    25
#>  4 FALSE          2        2 A1          8.08  1.75    25  1.48  1.08    25
#>  5 FALSE          0        1 A2         60.3  21.5     13 28.9  13.9     13
#>  6 FALSE          0        1 A2         82.9  11.4     13 28.9  13.9     13
#>  7 FALSE          8        4 A2         60.3  21.5     13 28.9  13.9     13
#>  8 FALSE          8        4 A2         82.9  11.4     13 28.9  13.9     13
#>  9 FALSE          0        1 A2         74.3  11.4     13 32.5  18.8     13
#> 10 FALSE          0        1 A2         88.7  11.8     13 32.5  18.8     13
#> # ... with 512 more rows, and 2 more variables: outcome <int>, time <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Based on requirement stated in comments below, the following strategy is suggessted, but output now will also differ in number of rows as all the new columns desired to be included in output don't have same values.

```
cols <- c('rev.sign', 'time_wk', 'time_cat')

dat %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
            dplyr::select(all_of(cols), study.name, n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
            pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
            dplyr::select(all_of(cols), study.name, mT = mpre_FALSE, sdT = sdpre_FALSE,
                          nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpre_TRUE, sdC = sdpre_TRUE, nC = n_TRUE, outcome) %>% 
            mutate(time = 0)
  ) %>%
  bind_rows(
    dat %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
      map_dfr(~ .x %>%
                dplyr::select(all_of(cols), study.name, n, mpos, sdpos, control, outcome, post) %>% 
                pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpos, sdpos, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
                dplyr::select(all_of(cols), study.name, mT = mpos_FALSE,sdT = sdpos_FALSE,nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpos_TRUE,
                              sdC = sdpos_TRUE,nC = n_TRUE,outcome,time = post) %>% unique
      )
  ) %>% unnest(everything()) %>% unique %>% arrange(study.name)

# A tibble: 522 x 12
   rev.sign time_wk time_cat study.name    mT   sdT    nT    mC   sdC    nC outcome  time
   <lgl>      <int>    <int> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <int> <dbl>
 1 FALSE          0        1 A1          1.68  1.07    25  1.44  1.08    25       1     0
 2 FALSE          2        2 A1          1.68  1.07    25  1.44  1.08    25       1     0
 3 FALSE          0        1 A1          7.4   2.22    25  1.08  1.12    25       1     1
 4 FALSE          2        2 A1          8.08  1.75    25  1.48  1.08    25       1     2
 5 FALSE          0        1 A2         60.3  21.5     13 28.9  13.9     13       1     0
 6 FALSE          0        1 A2         82.9  11.4     13 28.9  13.9     13       1     0
 7 FALSE          8        4 A2         60.3  21.5     13 28.9  13.9     13       1     0
 8 FALSE          8        4 A2         82.9  11.4     13 28.9  13.9     13       1     0
 9 FALSE          0        1 A2         74.3  11.4     13 32.5  18.8     13       1     1
10 FALSE          0        1 A2         88.7  11.8     13 32.5  18.8     13       1     1
# ... with 512 more rows
```

See the same with `study.name`

```
dat %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
            dplyr::select(study.name, n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
            pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
            dplyr::select(study.name, mT = mpre_FALSE, sdT = sdpre_FALSE,
                          nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpre_TRUE, sdC = sdpre_TRUE, nC = n_TRUE, outcome) %>% 
            mutate(time = 0)
  ) %>%
  bind_rows(
    dat %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
      map_dfr(~ .x %>%
                dplyr::select(study.name, n, mpos, sdpos, control, outcome, post) %>% 
                pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpos, sdpos, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
                dplyr::select(study.name, mT = mpos_FALSE,sdT = sdpos_FALSE,nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpos_TRUE,
                              sdC = sdpos_TRUE,nC = n_TRUE,outcome,time = post) %>% unique
      )
  ) %>% unnest(everything()) %>% unique %>% arrange(study.name)
# A tibble: 421 x 9
   study.name    mT   sdT    nT    mC   sdC    nC outcome  time
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <int> <dbl>
 1 A1          1.68  1.07    25  1.44  1.08    25       1     0
 2 A1          7.4   2.22    25  1.08  1.12    25       1     1
 3 A1          8.08  1.75    25  1.48  1.08    25       1     2
 4 A2         60.3  21.5     13 28.9  13.9     13       1     0
 5 A2         82.9  11.4     13 28.9  13.9     13       1     0
 6 A2         74.3  11.4     13 32.5  18.8     13       1     1
 7 A2         88.7  11.8     13 32.5  18.8     13       1     1
 8 A2         68.9  15.0     13 39.9  20.8     13       1     2
 9 A2         90.3   8.4     13 39.9  20.8     13       1     2
10 B1         67.6  19.3     17 51.9  28.3     20       1     0
# ... with 411 more rows
```

*Check that output for `A1` contains 3 rows in one output and 4 rows in another*

---

**Earlier answer** Some of the redundancy can be reduced by this

```
foo1 <- function(data){
  
  pre <- data %>% dplyr::select(n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
    pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
    dplyr::select(mT = mpre_FALSE, sdT = sdpre_FALSE,nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpre_TRUE, sdC = sdpre_TRUE, nC = n_TRUE,outcome) %>% 
    unique %>% mutate(time = 0)
  
  pos <- data %>% dplyr::select(n, mpos, sdpos, control, outcome, post) %>% 
    pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpos, sdpos, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
    dplyr::select(mT = mpos_FALSE,sdT = sdpos_FALSE,nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpos_TRUE,sdC = sdpos_TRUE,nC = n_TRUE,outcome,time = post) %>% unique
  
  bind_rows(pre,pos) %>% tidyr::unnest(everything())
  
}
```

However, you may do this in one single pipeline like this. You may tweak the `map_*` as per expected output format i.e. a dataframe or a list, etc.

```
dat %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
        dplyr::select(study.name, n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
        pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
          dplyr::select(mT = mpre_FALSE, sdT = sdpre_FALSE,nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpre_TRUE, sdC = sdpre_TRUE, nC = n_TRUE,outcome) %>% 
          unique %>% mutate(time = 0)
      ) %>%
  bind_rows(
    dat %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
      map_dfr(~ .x %>%
                dplyr::select(study.name, n, mpos, sdpos, control, outcome, post) %>% 
                pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpos, sdpos, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
                dplyr::select(mT = mpos_FALSE,sdT = sdpos_FALSE,nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpos_TRUE,sdC = sdpos_TRUE,nC = n_TRUE,outcome,time = post) %>% unique
                )
  ) %>% unnest(everything())

# A tibble: 423 x 8
      mT   sdT    nT    mC   sdC    nC outcome  time
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <int> <dbl>
 1  1.68  1.07    25  1.44  1.08    25       1     0
 2 60.3  21.5     13 28.9  13.9     13       1     0
 3 82.9  11.4     13 28.9  13.9     13       1     0
 4 67.6  19.3     17 51.9  28.3     20       1     0
 5 53.1  21.7     18 51.9  28.3     20       1     0
 6 59.4  18.4     20 51.9  28.3     20       1     0
 7 87.1  13.2     12 85.6   8.89    12       1     0
 8 90.6   8.79    27 85.6   8.89    12       1     0
 9 83.1  12.5     12 85.6   8.89    12       1     0
10 62.5  12.0     13 60.2  17.6     13       1     0
# ... with 413 more rows
```

The results [`benchmarking`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rbenchmark/versions/1.0.0/topics/benchmark) for speed

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark('reza' = {lapply(split(dat, dat$study.name), foo)},
          'anil' = {lapply(split(dat, dat$study.name), foo1)},
          'purr' = {dat %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
              map_dfr(~ .x %>%
                        dplyr::select(study.name, n, mpre, sdpre, control, outcome, post) %>% 
                        pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpre, sdpre, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
                        dplyr::select(mT = mpre_FALSE, sdT = sdpre_FALSE,nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpre_TRUE, sdC = sdpre_TRUE, nC = n_TRUE,outcome) %>% 
                        unique %>% mutate(time = 0)
              ) %>%
              bind_rows(
                dat %>% group_split(study.name) %>%
                  map_dfr(~ .x %>%
                            dplyr::select(study.name, n, mpos, sdpos, control, outcome, post) %>% 
                            pivot_wider(values_from = c(mpos, sdpos, n), names_from = control, values_fn = list) %>%
                            dplyr::select(mT = mpos_FALSE,sdT = sdpos_FALSE,nT = n_FALSE,mC = mpos_TRUE,sdC = sdpos_TRUE,nC = n_TRUE,outcome,time = post) %>% unique
                  )
              ) %>% unnest(everything())},
          replications = 10)

  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2 anil           10   14.99    1.624     14.94     0.03         NA        NA
3 purr           10    9.23    1.000      9.17     0.05         NA        NA
1 reza           10   25.33    2.744     25.23     0.05         NA        NA
```

The results with `microbenchmark`

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
 reza 1388.6720 1480.1678 2127.733 1587.3243 3361.978 3749.096    10
 anil 1055.8224 1060.3372 1328.847 1086.8156 1259.200 3206.637    10
 purr  898.9936  902.0576 1095.040  941.0366  976.386 2451.063    10
```

Comment: What's "benchmarking" can you possibly demonstrate it here? I think "group_split()" is slower than "split()".

Comment: Anil, thank you soooo much! A quick follow-up, if we want to also include columns: `"study.name"`,`"rev.sign"`,`"time_wk"`,`"time_cat"`,`"treats"` from [my input data.frame](https://github.com/rnorouzian/m2/blob/main/f.csv) into the final output your `purrr` solution and then `arrange(study.name)`, is that possible?

Comment: More generally, if you turn your `purrr` solution into a function, and then you add an argument called `dot.names` that accepts a vector of names of any length like: `"study.name","rev.sign","time_wk","time_cat","treats"`, and then the columns corresponding to `dot.names` be added to the final output ? -- Thank you!

Comment: I am seeing your data.frame.  Though the study.name are same across `pre` and `pos` data, other variables like `treats` etc. are not same.  If included, these will create different rows instead of format as you expect.  Can you suggest/show me your expected output after including all these variables for `study.name == 'A1'` i.e. first 4 rows

Comment: Anil I think you didn't use @rnorouzian and I didn't see your message at all (sorry!). For now, don't worry about that part, would you please simply turn your `purrr` solution into a function, and then add an argument called `dot.names` that accepts a vector of names of any length like: `"study.name","rev.sign","time_wk","time_cat","treats"`, and then the columns corresponding to `dot.names` be added to the final output ?

Comment: Thank you Anil! Now I understand what you meant, after adding the `cols` vector the data.frame goes from `423` rows to `524` rows. I want to try something. Is is possible to avoid rows for which `control==TRUE` when adding the cols vector?

Comment: @rnorouzian, I am not getting what do you mean?  Actually if you combine two or more rows into one, the variables with different values have to be aggregated .. Or first you have to think of an expected outcome let's say for study.name == A1